# How can we detect particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation

A constant velocity particle (charged or uncharged) can only be detected if its velocity is made to change, e.g. by scattering another particle or radiation off it. 
If it's velocity remains constant, this means it hasn't interacted with anything else in the universe and therefore can't have had its position measured.

Is this 100% correct ?

Comment: Well, rather put it this way: particles can only be detected if they interact with something.

Comment: What would you measure the position of the universe against? Classical particles can, of course, be detected without changing their velocity. Your statement is therefor theory dependent.

Comment: @CuriousOne What method would you use to detect a particle without changing it's velocity (classically) ?

Comment: @garyp: I let it interact with test masses of arbitrarily small mass. Trust me, in practice measuring the location of the Earth particle doesn't do anything measurable to its position. :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne So we're left wondering if the OP was asking a theoretical question or a practical question.

Comment: @garyp: If he was asking a physics question it always boils down to an experimental one, in the end. At least I don't buy into "theory" that can't be translated into experiment.

Comment: indeed but it's available for only one particular particle. You can prepare similar particles and do a stat on their behaviors and then, statistically predict the behaviors of the next particles, if such thing exists :)